# GlobalScope vs LifecycleOwner:CoroutineScope

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, android-lifecycle, kotlinx.coroutines

assuming that CoroutineScope is implemented by some lifecycle-aware component like `Presenter`.
when is it preferable to use GlobalScope.produce vs CoroutineScope.produce;

```
interface IPresenter, CoroutineScope {
  fun state(): ReceiveChannel<Event>
}

class Presenter(
  override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
): IPresenter, DefaultLifecycleObserver {
  fun state(): ReceiveChannel<Event> = GlobalScope.produce {
    send( SomeEvent() )
  }

  fun someOperation() = produce {
    send( SomeEvent() )
  }

  override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
    coroutineContext.cancel()
    owner.lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
  } 
}
```

when is the ReceiveChannel returned by `state()` cancelled? is this a memory leak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/produce.html) states:

> The running coroutine is cancelled when its receive channel is cancelled.

Additionally, it states

> **Note: This is an experimental api.** Behaviour of producers that work as children in a parent scope with respect to cancellation and error handling may change in the future.

Conclusion: the behavior when the parent scope is cancelled is unspecified and liable to change in the future.

This is why it's the best option to use `GlobalScope` for the producer and use the returned `ReceiveChannel` to explicitly control the lifecycle. The channel won't get automatically closed/cancelled.